# Does a virtual environment clone the folders under Home?

Tags: 16.04, virtualenv

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to effectively use virtualenv. I made a test environment called "quandl". In this environment I imported the Quandl package and am playing around with some examples from their site.

While in my virtual environment, when I type `ls` I see my home directory and all its sub-folders. Does the test environment create its own copies of each of those folders? If that's the case, then with every virtual environment I create from here on out I will see different folders every time I load a new environment. Not necessarily a bad thing, I just want to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a virtual environment does not clone the directories in `$HOME`. A virtual environment is an isolated project-specific environment for invoking the Python interpreter and installing Python packages. This allows you to isolate the Python dependencies of multiple projects from each other.

Comment: But then if I install a certain version of a package that I need for a specific project, where does this package get installed to? And how would another virtual environment know to ignore this package?

Comment: That is what activation (and deactivation) of a virtual environment does: to specify the virtual environment that you want to use (activate) and installation will then be specific to that activated virtual environment.

Comment: Is there any way I can see the different virtual environments that I am creating? Like, do they get stored somewhere?

Comment: You can do it by giving the all virtual environments the same name (common ones I see are `venv` and `env`) and then search for these names. You can also check out `virtualenvwrapper` which provides a way to manage multiple virtual environments.